# Independence and density of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

For some $r>0$, the distribution of pair $(X, Y)$ of real random variables has the joint density function $f(x,y):=c1_{\{(s,t)|s^2+t^2\leq r^2\}}(x,y).$ Are $X$ and $Y$ independent? And how to determine the constant $c$ and the density  of $X$ and $X-Y?$

I have managed to find the constant $c:$
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y) dxdy = 1$$
$$ \int\int_{\{ x^2+y^2\leq r^2 \}} c = 1$$
$$  cr^2\pi = 1 \Rightarrow c = \frac{1}{r^2 \pi} $$

And I also managed to get marginal distributions by integration $f(x,y)$ with respect to each variable and I get $$f_X(x)=2c\sqrt{r^2-x^2}=\frac{2}{r^2\pi}\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$$
$$ f_Y(y)=2c\sqrt{r^2-y^2}=\frac{2}{r^2\pi}\sqrt{r^2-y^2} $$

1. I should check if the two random variables are independent and I was going to see if $$f(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y)$$ holds and my guess is, that it doesn´t since I cannot see how this product yields 1 but I need more formal mathematical argument for it.
2. I am also supposed to find the density of $X-Y$. So I thought of using the formula:
   $$ f_{X-Y}(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(z+y)f_Y(y)dy$$
   Is this the best way to proceed and also if someone could tell me if pdfs are correct?

I would appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: Find the marginal distributions, check if the joint distribution is the product of the marginals for independence. A joint density must integrate to $1$, being a probability. You can calculate the individial densities of $X$ and $Y$ by integrating out the respective factors, and of $X-Y$ using the joint density.

Comment: Marginal distributions should be obtained by integrating f(x,y) with respect to each variable, right? If that's true, I don't know how to proceed with this kind of integral with an indicator function, that's the point where I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Ah, had you written this in the question above, it would not have been closed. Remember, anything you can say about your problem counts as context, even the definitions of simple things, or a plan in your head. Coming to the question, the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y)dx$, for a fixed $y$, becomes $c\int 1_{x^2+y^2 \leq r^2} dx$, which then becomes $c \int 1_{x^2 \leq r^2 - y^2} dx$. The integral of the indicator of a set is the measure of that set, so the answer for fixed $y$ is $c \mu(\{x : x^2 \leq r^2-y^2\}) = 2c\sqrt{r^2-y^2}$, once you recognize that the set is an interval.

Comment: You should mention the support of the marginal distributions, namely $(-r,r)$. Now $X$ and $Y$ are clearly not independent because $\operatorname{support}(X)\times \operatorname{support}(Y)\ne \operatorname{support}(X,Y)$. Hence you cannot apply that convolution formula for the density of $X-Y$. Consider finding the cdf of $X-Y$ or use a change of variables to find the pdf directly.

Comment: Thank you! Did I get it right, the point is that I don't even have to bother with the function values if they are not equal to 0 in the same area?
And could you give me a hint on how to find the cdf of X-Y?